# Javascript v3 Google maps rotate map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, rotation, compass-geolocation

I cant seem to find anything about this anywhere. Its because i am  trying to make the map rotate around the user. google maps javascript v3 doesnt seem to be doing this. wanting to ask google personally, their homepage directed me to stackoverflow. Is this at all possible? If not, have anyone heard the developers talk about implementing this feature in the future, or will it simple never be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Compass datas aren't available in the JS API V3
Don't hesitate to refer to the documentation to see your possibilities using it
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Google also update frequently the experimental version of its API, you can follow the changes 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference

Answer (score 1):

Could be a fun project to work out with css3 options.

Just rotate the whole map container.

Comment: rotating the entire container even rotates the text written (location names) wriiten in it

Answer (score 0):

What about setHeading? I believe that rotates the entire frame relative to the cardinal directions.

Comment: setHeading is only for aerial imagery, meaning it will only work for SATELLITE and HYBRID map types, within some locations, and at some zoom levels.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en